# android gpu image rendering issue

Tags: android, android-listview, gpuimage, android-gpuimageview

I'm currently building an android app to apply filter on a bmp. I'm using the gpuimage lib. How it's done is that the bmp is show in a ListView which contain 8 filters. When scrolling down/up, we request the filtering of the bmp (b&w, sepia...). As the rendering take times, I display in my listview the original bmp and it's replace by the filtered image once done

Here is how the  activity do it.

```
private ListView mFiltersView;


private void FiltersPreview(final Bitmap mBmp) {

    boolean mPreview = true;

    mPreviewBitmap = resizeBitmap(mBmp);

    mCameraImageFiltersAdapter = new CameraImageFiltersAdapter(this, mPreviewBitmap, mPreview);
    mFiltersView.setAdapter(mCameraImageFiltersAdapter);
    mFiltersView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            mCameraImageFiltersAdapter.cancel();
            mFiltersView.cancelPendingInputEvents();
            mFiltersView.setAdapter(null);
            final CameraFiltersFactory effect = (CameraFiltersFactory) v.findViewById(R.id.filteredImage).getTag();
            BufferAnimationDrawable Loading = new BufferAnimationDrawable(getBaseContext());
            Loading.setPrimaryColor(0xfffb633e);
            LoadingScreen.setImageDrawable(Loading);
            LoadingScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mFiltersView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            getActionBar().hide();

                if(mBmp == null) Log.d(TAG,"mBitmap is null");
                effect.save(mBmp, position, new GPUImage.OnPictureSavedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPictureSaved(Uri uri) {
                        final Intent previewIntent = new Intent(FiltersSelectionActivity.this, PicturePreviewActivity.class);
                        previewIntent.setData(uri);
                        previewIntent.setAction(mActionTypes.toString());
                        previewIntent.putExtra("Type", "Filtered");
                        startActivityForResult(previewIntent, 0);
                    }
                });
            }

    });
}
```

The mCameraImageFiltersAdapter is defined as :

```
 public CameraImageFiltersAdapter(/*Activity activity, */Context c, Bitmap current, boolean isPreview) {
    mContext = c;
    mPreview = isPreview;
    mCurrentBitmap = current;

    mFilterIds = CAMERA_IMAGE_FILTERS == null
        || CAMERA_IMAGE_FILTERS.length == 0 ?
        mFilterIds : CAMERA_IMAGE_FILTERS;
    mFakeBitmap = mCurrentBitmap;
    mFakeBitmap.setDensity(0);
    mExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);


}

private final Handler handler = new Handler();// handler to display images

public int getCount() { return mFilterIds.length; }
public long getItemId(int position) { return 0; }
public Object getItem(int position) { return null; }
@Override public int getViewTypeCount() { return mFilterIds.length; }
@Override public int getItemViewType(int position) { return position; }

final int stub_id = R.drawable.filter_preview_stub;

public ImageView filteredImage = null;
public TextView filteredText = null;

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    mPosition = position;
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item_filter, null);
        filteredImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.filteredImage);
        filteredImage.setImageBitmap(mFakeBitmap);

        filteredText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);

        queueFiltered(filteredImage, mPosition, filteredText);

    }

    return convertView;
}

private void queueFiltered(final ImageView view, final int position, final TextView text) {

    final CameraFiltersFactory holder = new CameraFiltersFactory(mContext, view, text);
    if(holder != null)
        mExecutorService.submit(new FilterLoader(holder, position));
}

public void cancel() {
    if(mExecutorService != null) mExecutorService.shutdownNow();
}
```

The CameraFilterFactoy is just a easy to use class to access to the GPUImage

```
 public class CameraFiltersFactory {

private static final String TAG = CameraFiltersFactory.class.getSimpleName();

private final ImageView mImageView;
private final GPUImage mCameraImage;
private Bitmap mFilteredBitmap;
private int mCurrentEffect;
private Context mContext;
private Activity mActivity = null;
private TextView mFiltersText;

public CameraFiltersFactory(Context c, ImageView filteredImage, TextView filteredText) {

    mImageView = filteredImage;
    mImageView.setTag(this);

    mContext = c;
    mCameraImage = new GPUImage(mContext);

    if(filteredText != null) {
        mFiltersText = filteredText;
        mFiltersText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if(mImageView != null) mActivity = (Activity) mContext;
}

public void generateFilteredBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int filtertype, boolean isPreview) {
    mCurrentEffect = filtertype;

    switch (mCurrentEffect) {
     case R.id.blackandwhite:
         mCameraImage.setFilter(new GPUImagePlusGrayscaleFilter(isPreview));
         break;
     case R.id.cool:
         mCameraImage.setFilter(new GPUImagePlusCoolFilter(isPreview));
         break;
     case R.id.cool2:
         mCameraImage.setFilter(new GPUImagePlusCool2Filter(isPreview));
         break;
     case R.id.faded:
         mCameraImage.setFilter(new GPUImagePlusFadedFilter(mContext, isPreview));
        break;
     case R.id.hipster:
         mCameraImage.setFilter(new GPUImagePlusHipsterFilter(mContext, isPreview));
        break;
     case R.id.sepia:
         mCameraImage.setFilter(new GPUImagePlusSepiaFilter(isPreview));
        break;
     case R.id.vivid:
         mCameraImage.setFilter(new GPUImagePlusVividFilter(isPreview));
         break;
     case R.id.warm:
         mCameraImage.setFilter(new GPUImagePlusWarmFilter(mContext, isPreview));
         break;
     default:
         Log.d("NONE", "None FAIT CHIER");
         break;
    }

    mCameraImage.deleteImage();
    mCameraImage.setImage(bmp);
    mFilteredBitmap = mCameraImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied();

}



@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public void save(Bitmap bitmap, int filter_id, GPUImage.OnPictureSavedListener ofsl) {
    Log.d("NONE", "Save request with filter: "+filter_id);
    generateFilteredBitmap(bitmap, filter_id, false);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String fileName = timeStamp + ".jpg";
    mCameraImage.saveToPictures(mFilteredBitmap, CameraSettings.CAMERA_ROLL_FOLDER, fileName, true, ofsl);
}

}
```

This code is working fine in the List view.

Once I click on a picture from the ListView, I get his position, stop Executor from the adapter and ask to the FilterFactory for a rendering.

If In the listview I wait that all the preview list image are showing the filter rendering, and then I click, the filter is correctly applied on the original bmp.

In case, I'm scrolling quickly down and the GPU is in progress to render the preview iamge and then click, the original bmp is not filtered. I have check that in both case, when I click the list view give the right filter position and that the case. It seems that if a rendering is in progress, I'm not able to cancel and ask for a new one.

Any idea why ? Any idea if I can cancel the current GPU rendering and start a new one. ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use gpuImage.deleteImage(); method in your adapter class after getting the bitmap from the gpu image.

Before setting your image to the GPUImage, create your image thumbnail. So it will load fast.

```
GPUImaage gpuImage=new GPUImage(context);
gpuImage.setImage(your image);
gpuImage.setFilter(choose your filter);
gpuImage.requestRender();

imageView.setImageBitmap(gpuImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied());

gpuImage.deleteImage();
```